# How to launch PowerShell script from the OS command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have a PowerShell script for building my project files, and I'd like to have capability to run it from my file manager's command line (and, possibly, make a shortcut to this script so I can start build from my desktop)
Any way to do this?

Comment: I've started using PowerShell for a command prompt instead of cmd.exe/command.com. Provides all of the same functionality, but you get instant access to all of the PS capabilities, as well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you're on PowerShell 2.0 use:

```
PowerShell.exe -File c:\users\john\myscript.ps1
```

If you're on 1.0 use:

```
PowerShell -Command "& {c:\users\john\myscript.ps1}"
```

Depending on what you do/load in your profile script you may also want to specify `-NoProfile`.  Of course, if your script requires something that is loaded in your profile then don't use this parameter.  Otherwise, it can speed up execution of your script a bit.

Comment: In windows 10 this doesn't run by default, it's a matter of security!

Comment: Yes but anyone using PowerShell is going to pretty quickly figure out they need to set the PowerShell execution policy to something other than `Restricted`.

Answer (score -9):

invoke-command -computername -scriptblock{param()} -ArgumentList